# "Virtual recycle bin" for DFS?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dfs, dfs-r

Does anyone know any way to have a "virtual recycle bin" for a server that makes DFS? I've been googling and not get anything straight.

At my company we do daily incremental backups of everything, but today, the backup software has crushed a complete copy and what had not been able to recover since the incremental copy had not seen any change in the archives since it became the complete copy.

With  "the virtual recycle bin" I mean that if someone deletes something from DFS can recover quickly without pulling backups ...

Thanks in advance!

PS:Sorry for my english

Comment: http://www.condusiv.com/products/undelete. - Also, this statement makes no sense: "the backup software has crushed a complete copy and what had not been able to recover since the incremental copy had not seen any change in the archives since it became the complete copy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If volume shadow copy enabled on one machine you can try to revert to previous version of a file. This will not replicate by DFS but you can try to separate a Computer from the DFS scenario and revert to previous version of the files, in the next step you can set this machine as DFS primary. But this only works if you have volume shadow copy enabled on one of the machines.